# ASP.NET Web Form call BinaryWrite() 3 times

Tags: asp.net, .net

**ASP.NET Web Form call BinaryWrite() 3 times**
when I debug the code below
It execute more time, and not stop

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = "a.txt"; 
        FileStream Stream2 = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(a), FileMode.Open); 
        long length = Stream2.Length;
        byte[] d = new byte[length];
        Stream2.Read(d, 0, Convert.ToInt32(length)); 
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("a.txt")));
        Response.BinaryWrite(d); 
        Stream2.Close(); 
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use `Stream.Copy` directly to the `HttpRequest`’s response stream?

Comment: BTW, for non-HTML responses in Classic ASP.NET you should use an `IHttpHandler` (optionally with an `*.ashx` file)

Comment: ashx also have this problem, the code just for reproduction  the problem

Comment: You have this on page load? That means it will run each time for any event, any button click, and any operations that occur on this page - not sure if that makes a whole lot of sense.